# Elasticsearch searching - span_near query with analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I need help to comprehend Elasticsearch behavior while searching the words in some text field. I have a text field 'description' which mapping looks like:

```
description: {
    type: "text"
    analyzer: "lower_ascii"
    fielddata: true
}
```

with settings:

```
lower_ascii: {
    filter: [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
    ],
    type: "custom"
    tokenizer: "standard"
}
```

So it is tokenized by standard tokenizer and modifield to lower ascii. 
If the field contains text e.g. **'ÁÁÁ XXX YYY ŽŽŽ'** it creates tokens like **'aaa', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'**. 
Then if I would like to search docs which contains all words 'aaa zzz' in the field it does not work with match or match_phase query. So I found out **span_near** query which looks like it works right but it **does not apply the lower_ascii analyzer** on the search value. 
My query looks like:

```
'query': {
        'span_near': {
            'clauses': {
                {'span_term': {'description' => 'aaa'}},
                {'span_term': {'description' => 'zzz'}}
            },
            "slop": 50,
            "in_order": FALSE
        }
    }
```

This works as I need (if I understand it) BUT if I tried to search 'ÁÁÁ ŽŽŽ' the result is empty(aaa zzz works well). Is there a way to set up lower_ascii analyzer in query or is there a better way to do it in better way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `match_phrase` query is the one you may want to use. It supports configurable slop.

```
{
  "query":
  { "match_phrase": { "description": { "query": "<query>" , slop: <slop>} } }
}
```